# Complete domain redirect (301) - All version to https://example.com

Tags: .htaccess, http, redirect

Looking to redirect an entire domain to its https://example.com version for any variants that are requested (http://, https://www., and www.) in the most SEO friendly way possible.

(I am aware that there are a lot of similar Q/A's, but they seem to be specific so I decided to start with a clean post).

I am currently using this:

```
RewriteEngine On 
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80 
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
```

But I have been told that the redirect is not 301, and it also does not redirect the https://www. version.

Is there a simple way to do this all in one go?

Thank you in advance!

Take care

Comment: It's not redirecting because of the `%{SERVER_PORT} 80` bit. A 301 needs `[R=301,L]`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a single rule in your site root .htaccess for this:

```
RewriteEngine On

# remove www and turn on https in same rule
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Use a new browser to test the change.

Comment: Thank you for the incredibly quick reply @anubhava. It is working! Would have marked it already but you were so fast that I need to wait for a few minutes.